# DWORD multiplication in python

Tags: python

I have a problem, for which an answer I've been looking for too long.

In one application, written in PowerBuilder, there has been a bug (which has not been spotted on time), which went as follows - `long * long` results in `long` (not in `longlong`), due to what the output was somehow strange. Now I need to do the same in python. For example:

```
a = 3423729
b = 96300
c = a*b = 329705102700
```

PowerBuilder says:

```
c = a*b = -1007379092
```

Due to further tests, it seems like it is a signed 32-bit integer, but I couldn't make python return me such result. Anyways, using calc and making him go with dword multiplication, result is `-1007379092`. Any clue how to resolve that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ctypes` package:

```
>>> from ctypes import c_int32
>>> a = 3423729
>>> b = 96300
>>> c_int32(a*b).value
-1007379092
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your application is taking the rightmost 32 bits of the result, represented as a 32 bit int.

You can use the types in the `ctypes` library to represent signed/unsigned integers of a specific size, in a similar manner. For a signed 32 bit int:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> c = 329705102700
>>> ctypes.c_int32(c).value
-1007379092
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do that because Python allocates storage dynamically specifically to avoid integer overflow. If you really want to duplicate the overflow, you may try the following:

```
import ctypes

a, b = 3423729, 96300
c = ctypes.c_int(a * b)
print(c.value)
```